# Netlogo - Behaviour Space overwriting a set variable

Tags: netlogo

I am using BehaviourSpace to run simulations. In my code I set variable A (near-radius in this case) to be 0,25 of variable B (detection-range), but in BehaviourSpace I set variable A to a fixed value, and I have a multitude of values for variable B.

Code:

```
set near-radius detection-range / 4
```

BehaviourSpace:

```
["near-radius" 4]
["detection-range" 2 8 14 20]
```

When I run these simulations will variable A stay at that fixed value of 4, or does is change according to my code (to 0.5, 2, 3.5, 5)? What takes precedence, the code, or BehaviourSpace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code takes precedence. Think of BehaviorSpace providing the initial values to your global variables, or as the value that would be on a slider or other input widget. If you have the slider named my-slide set to 5 and somewhere in your code it says `set my-slide my-slide + 2`, then the slider will actually move to reflect the updated value of the global variable.

To get the flexibility you want, you can use `if [behaviorspace-run-number = 0] [set near-radius detection-range / 4]` or similar. This will only run your code line when the model is not controlled by BehaviorSpace.